# Centering a div within a div

Tags: html, css

I know it should be a fairly easy thing to do but for some reason I'm having issues with it and not sure why. I'm adding a controller under the gallery that you can use to scroll through the slides and need to it be centered.

This is what the code looks like ATM:

```
<div class="control_wrap" style="">
    <div class="gallery_controls" style="">
       <a target="_blank"></a> <a target="_blank"></a> <a target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.control_wrap{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.gallery_controls{
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks.

Comment: why the `float: left;` ?

Comment: float & margin:0 auto; are not work together

Comment: updated my answer to reflect your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get rid of the float: left on .gallery_controls. margin: 0 auto won't work otherwise.

Comment: Ok, so i have removed the float on both divs and added a height but now the elements are floating on the top of gallery for some reason.

Comment: You'll want to keep the float on the parent container. Just get rid of it on .gallery_controls.

Answer (score 0):

in order for `margin:0 auto;` to work, you have to specify a width on that div and omit the float.

If you also want to vertically center your div, you need either `position:absolute` on the div, or `display:table-cell`on the parent div with `vertical-align:middle`.

Something like this:

```
parent{
   position:relative;
}

child{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   width: <your-width>;
   height: <your-height>;
   margin-left: <your-width> / 2;
   margin-top: <your-height> / 2;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/ygVgn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove float left from this class:

```
.gallery_controls{

margin:0 auto;
/*float:left;*/
width:50%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to something like this:

```
.control_wrap {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.gallery_controls {
    margin:0 auto;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
}​
```

Result http://jsfiddle.net/AmAMP/1/

Comment: Hence the first word: **Change**. As shown on the output page!

Comment: again, there is no `float:center`, only `left`,`right`or `none`are allowed as keywords.

Comment: Ok thanks all for your replied, I have managed to get the div to center but a tags inside are not being centered. I guess i need to apply the same logic to them.

Comment: Oh! My bad. It should've been text-align. Editing the reply! Thanks @Christoph

Answer (score 0):

I have updated see your **CSS** please check it:-

```
.gallery_controls{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

or you can see the live example for easier understanding :- 
http://jsfiddle.net/cPk53/5/

Answer (score -1):

Use Tables instead. With div the look and feel would vary from browser to browser. The moment you feel that you have done it, loading in another browser or an older version of the browser will break your illusion.

Comment: `div` is a general block-element without special semantical annotation, whereas  `table` is designated for the presentation of tabular data. Especially for layout-structuring `table` should be avoided, because it lags the flexibility you can achieve with `div`s. See [ZenGarden](http://www.csszengarden.com) for an example of how flexible `div`- Layout can be.